# define gets ignored by target_compile_definitions

Tags: makefile, build, cmake

I am looking to build a library and I need to pass two defines to that build, but cmake's **target_compile_definitions()** scrambles them in a manner that renders them unusable.

The two defines are:

- `-D'_LIB_EXCEPTION_ABI=__attribute__((visibility("default")))'`
- `-D'_LIB_FALLTHROUGH()=((void)0)'`

Unfortunately, the first one gets translated to (in the command build line):

- `-D'_LIB_EXCEPTION_ABI="\__attribute__((visibility(\"default\")))'"`

While the second one is missing altogether from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake has [known limitations](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) on what compile definitions could be.

Among these limitations are *function-style* definitions (`_LIB_FALLTHROUGH()`) and ones containing double quotes (`"`).

Instead of attempting to overcome these limitations, it is recommended to create a **separate header file** with these compile definitions:

```
#define _LIB_EXCEPTION_ABI __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define _LIB_FALLTHROUGH() ((void)0)
```

This header file could be included with `-include` compiler option (gcc) or `/FI` option (Visual Studio).