# Define string literal macro in cmake add_definition

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

My code

```
set(MY_VERSION "01.00")
set(MY_MINOR_VERSION "02")
set(ALL_VERSION ${MY_VERSION}-${MY_MINOR_VERSION})
add_definitions(-DVERSION="${ALL_VERSION}")
```

in the compile_commands.json I see:

```
-DVERSION=\\\"01.00-02\\\"
```

In my IDE the macro is not correctly parsed but it's a side effect actually. My question: am I doing the correct thing? I would expect something like:

```
-DVERSION=\"01.00-02\"
```

Comment: CMake has [known limitation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) in what symbols can be used for compile definitions passed to the compiler via command line. In your case you may omit double quotes around the macro value but [stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value) it in the C/C++ code. See also that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61633185/3440745) to the related question.

Comment: [add_compile_definitions()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions) - CMake will automatically escape the value correctly for the native build system (note that CMake language syntax may require escapes to specify some values).

Comment: It seems not supported in cmake 2.8.11